# API to work with dropbox.com from .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, api, windows-8, windows-runtime, dropbox

I'm developing metro app using C# and XAML, i want to connect to Dropbox.com and retrieve files from dropbox, I tried to install dropbox API's from [here](http://nuget.org/packages/DropNet) and [here](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/) and some other links But when i install from `Package Manager Console(VS 2012)`, it fires an error during installation for all API's please check the image[image: Installation Error].
I understand that these version API's do not support for `framework 4.5`. Can anyone please tell me where i can find correct version that supports `framework 4.5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with .NET 4.5, it is the project type you selected that's the problem.  It selected the .NETCore profile, the one you get from a Portable Class Library project or a Windows Store project.  The library you are trying to use can only work in a desktop app.

You could use their [generic REST api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api).  Fuggedaboudit if this is a Store app, you can't keep the file transfer going when the user gets bored waiting.